# Knowing if a Google Plus person has a real picture

Tags: google-plus

I have an application that lists the users in your circles using the Google+ APIs. That works nicely except for one thing: the API does not say if a user has a picture or if the picture is just the placeholder (the blue silhouette).

https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/list

```
{
  "kind": "plus#person",
  "etag": etag,

  "id": string,
  "displayName": string,
  "image": {
    "url": string
  },
}
```

How do I determine if the picture is a placeholder? (so that I don't have to download it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Image URLs are there:

```
https://www.google.com/s2/photos/profile/{user_id}
https://plus.google.com/s2/photos/profile/{user_id}
https://profiles.google.com/s2/photos/profile/{user_id}
```

For now, a 404 is better than downloading the default picture. I'd still love the API to simply tell us that the user has not set a picture :(

Comment: There is an open feature request for this, currently. If you Star the issue, you will receive email updates on it.
https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=528

Answer (score 3):

response will have `isDefault: true` for the placeholder image

```
"image": {
  "url": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/.../photo.jpg?sz=50",
  "isDefault": true
 },
```